# What does the Gemara mean that anything given to the heart, it says by it “and you will fear your G-d”?

Tags: ki-teitzei, mishpatim, maseches-kiddushin

Kiddushin 32b:

> יכול יעצים עיניו כמי שלא ראהו ת"ל תקום ויראת דבר המסור ללב נאמר בו (ויקרא יט, יד) ויראת מאלהיך
>
> I might have thought he can close his eyes like one who did not see [the elder]; the Passuk teaches, “You will get up and fear [your G-d]” (Vayikra 19:14); anything given to the heart, it is said by it, “And you will fear your G-d.”

*Anything*? What about Hashavas Aveidah, where the same argument can be made: I might have thought I can hide my eyes as if I didn’t see the lost object and thereby exempt myself from having to return it; yet the passuk never says “fear your G-d” by returning a lost object, neither in Shemos 23:4 nor in Devarim 22:1-4. Why? Likewise aiding a struggling animal (Shemos 23:5), nor helping to load an animal (Devarim 22:5), nor Shiluach HaKan (Devarim 22:6-7), nor countless other mitzvos by which one who does not see the object is exempt - none of them say “you will fear your G-d” as a warning that you shouldn’t pretend like you didn’t see it.

I suppose this question can be asked in two ways: how can the Gemara say that “you will fear your G-d” is said by *anything* given to the heart, when we see it’s not? Alternatively, what is unique about standing for an elder which warrants this phrase to be used in this manner?

Comment: Shiluach HaKan is a bad example, you don't do it if you don't need the eggs/chicks.

Comment: If you choose to pick the second alternative, the answer might be here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106814/source-for-%d7%95%d7%99%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%9e%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%9a-because-of-loss-of-money/106837#106837

Comment: I think the word anything isn't a necessary translation

Comment: You don't always need the same phrase to convey the same principle. For example, "לא תוכל להתעלם" regarding *hashavas aveida* suggests that you "may not close your eyes as if you don't see it" (Rashi, *D'varim* 22:3). Likewise with the *p'rika ut'ina* examples you gave, "והתעלמת מהם" and "וחדלת מעזב לו" imply the same (and the *ki sir'eh/ lo sir'eh* wording is used by Chazal to expound the proximity at which you have to help). | Also, as mentioned above, the *shiluach hakan* example doesn't necessarily fit with your point.